# How to get started building C# and ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, crm

I am planning to create a Customer Relationship Management (CRM) application.  I have to use C# and Visual Studio 2008.  What is the best approach to get started and what resources can I use to make this process easier?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are asking this question in particular makes me think you are probably in over your head.

That being said, the best single resource I have found to walk you through the complete process of developing and ASP.NET web application is the "Problem Design Solution" series from wrox.  The ASP.NET 3.5 version (compatible with VS2008) is available at [http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-3-5-Website-Programming-Programmer/dp/0470187581](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187581) .  Basically, the book walks you through the process of building a web application using ASP.NET 3.5 from start to finish, and attempts to provide an overview of the most common features of the framework.  They also provide a sample application to accompany the code they are writing, so you can see how each chapter of information fits into the big picture.  Good luck.

Comment: +1 for "in over your head"...

Answer (score 2):

Official Microsoft tutorial:

if you want to use ASP.NET Web Forms:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/samples/tailspin-spyworks

if you want to use ASP.NET MVC:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store